# I am making an automated codedUI test in microsoft test manager 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, mtm

I have made:

1.recorded the coded UI test in visual studio 2013.

2.Configured the test controller on the main computer in team foundation server.

3.made new environment in lab centre in microsoft test manager 2013.

the problem is in last step the lab environment should configure the test agent automatically to run UI tests, but after i finish the environment the computer restarts and then I found that the name of the machine in the environment is changed to activate.adobe.com.

I removed all adobe products from the computer, and deactivated all adobe assistants from start up and the problem still there.

Please help me as I am new to testing.

Comment: check in the hosts file for an entry pointing activate.adobe.com to localhost

Comment: Thanks you for your comment, can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: https://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/checking-your-windows-hosts-file